# Google Chrome .dev not work over http

Tags: google-chrome, http, https, localhost

From last update of **Google Chrome 63.0.3239.84** the `.dev` domain of my local development machine does not work anymore becouse the browser force URL over https and I do not have a sicure certificate on my local machine. Is there a way to make it work with .dev?

I do not want to use other domains like `.local` or `.test`

I tried to enable/disable this `chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost` but nothing.

Comment: Yes, you can create a self-signed certificate for yourdomain.dev and make your OS and browser trust it. Then it will work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't change it.

Since 1999 that the Network Working Group(NWG) wrote a [memorandum](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606) listing the safe Top Level Domains(TLDs) for development.
Choose one of that list to have a future-proof solution.

Because some developers depend on some tools with this poor approach - I was one of them - you can use a hack to solve this: write `badidea` when the HSTS warning pops up.

Use this only as a temporary solution and dedicate your time upgrading, or helping upgrade, your tools.

EDIT: Other solutions [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/gQaakYNzfkQ;context-place=topicsearchin/chrome/category$3AStable%7Csort:relevance%7Cspell:false).

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no workaround to make .dev work in Chrome; it now belongs to Google.

https://laravel-news.com/chrome-63-now-forces-dev-domains-https