# Php live server not working on multiple browsers

Tags: php, google-chrome, http, firefox, browser

I have a dev site that I started up using the php live server and using localhost:8000. The issue I'm having is that neither Chrome, Firefox, or Safari are able to establish a secure connection because the protocol gets reverted to HTTPS, thus rendering my site useless. I'm fully aware of the new implementations that chrome and other browsers are placing on .dev sites, but I don't think that applies to my issue, especially since the dev site doesn't use that domain. Also, I've been to chrome://net-internals/#hsts and tried deleting any security constraints on localhost, but that didn't work either. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I think this post can help you: [Google Chrome .dev not work over http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47754347/google-chrome-dev-not-work-over-http).

So in according to this post you must only change your `.dev` local domain following this [memorandum](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606) from Network Working Group(NWG).

Comment: That's just it, I'm not using a `.dev` domain at all. My dev site originally used a standard `.com` domain. Since I found that I can just use the `php` live server, why would my localhost be redirected?

Comment: .com is equal to .dev becouse these domains are top-level so the browser force URL to a secure protocol. NOT USE A TOP-LEVEL DOMAIN (read memorandum of NWG, they explain that you can use .test or .local or .localhost)

Comment: For another test, I made a simple php project for MAMP to serve. It still throws the error, and there's no predesignated domain for it. It's the basic of basic tests to see if MAMP is serving it correctly. Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same error, stating `the site can't provide a secure connection`. Am I missing something here and just acting like a total noob? When the files get served through `localhost:port#` using MAMP, what determines its TLD as a .com or .dev and redirects it to HTTPS?

Comment: So you confirm that it isn't a problem related to the domain used?

Comment: As far as I know, that's correct. There's no config file, or any code that has a domain listed anywhere. I tested the test page on my server, hosted through IIS, and it works just fine, but even when run my dev site through IIS, I still get an error through there as well. Perhaps the issue is a little deeper than I suspect with the dev files. It was built years ago before I started maintaining it, and up until a month ago, it worked just fine. But no worries, I have a few other tricks up my sleeve. Thanks for your feedback!