# Prevent local site be forced HTTPS on Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, https

Chrome has been updated to force HTTPS on some preserved domain names, unfortunately one of my local machine hits the list. My machine name is "dev", Chrome now automatically redirect "http://dev/..." to "https://dev/..."

I have a lot of WordPress sites in "dev", of course there's no certificates installed as it a local development environment, so all the sites no longer work on Chrome. I'm wondering is it the only choice I change the machine name and all those site addresses to work again on Chrome? Any easier method?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47735877/how-to-stop-chrome-from-redirecting-to-https

Comment: @JoshLee but it's not ".dev", its "dev"

Comment: Are you implying that your version of Chrome is forcing HTTPS for "dev" for a different reason than everybody else's version of Chrome? Anyway, changing it to "dev.localhost" is still the suggested fix.

Comment: @JoshLee I don't care about reason, they say ".dev" will be redirected, that means `*.dev`, right? But "dev" is not "*.dev". I suppose it a mistake, if so, it should be fixed, but if not, then it's not just ".dev", but `*dev`, should we not to know that?

Comment: I've got the same issue since today. xxx.dev was working fine yesterday, today it's automatically redirected to https and no longer works, still works fine in other browsers

Answer (score 7):

Chrome latest version > 63.xxx will force all domains ending on .dev (and .foo) to be redirected to HTTPS via a preloaded HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) header.

it's good to use .local or .test for local development URLs.

check this link for more detail : https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/

Comment: @ankit patel : Can you please see what I am missing here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51003617/mamp-on-mac-redirects-virtual-localhost-to-https