# Firefox force dev domains to use SSL as well as Chrome

Tags: laravel, google-chrome, ssl, firefox, localhost

Today when I woke up to continue my developing process I got `Firefox` update and then I wasn't able to reach my `localhost` websites and redirecting to `HTTPS` protocol.

We all know that Google did the same while before but as many of us using Firefox mostly we (at least me) didn't care and continued our works with Firefox, now that Firefox decided to play with us (developers) here is some unanswered questions for me here:

## Questions

1. How do we add HTTPS to our localhost?
2. Should we buy SSL certificate for our local environment?
3. How do I add SSL to my laravel project on localhost?
4. What will happen if I develop application with SSL and when I move it to host my domain doesn't have SSL (will be any conflict there?)

## Concerns

My most concerns goes to:

1. What if I don't want to buy `SSL certificate` for my local environment and **Publish my projects data (such as names etc.) with others (basically SSL companies)**.
2. What if I develop with `HTTPS` and my live site is `HTTP`

## UPDATE

As I'm working on `Windows` and also I'm suing `Laragon` (i don't know about mapps,xampp etc.) here is how I solved my issue **But still looking for answer to my other questions**

First of all I turned on my laragon ssl certificate, then i changed my domains to `pp` now my sites loads like `domain.pp`

PS: I also tested same way with `.local`, `.test` and `.app` it didn't worked but `pp` worked.

Comment: I also like `.dev ` TLD, but do you really need to use it instead of other alternatives like `.test` or `.localhost`?

Comment: find anwer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47785025/prevent-local-site-be-forced-https-on-chrome/47879317#47879317

Answer (score 1):

You can also change the domain suffix.

just like

- .localhost
- .invalid
- .test
- .example

Comment: `localhost` & `test` didn't work as well, but `pp` worked.

Answer (score 0):

The folks that created DesktopServer (which I ***highly**** recommend over MAMP/XAMPP) registered the domain .dev.cc  for local development use when Google did its thing with dev, which, as we all know, now requires https for local work when you use Chrome or Firefox.  When you use DesktopServer to install a new instance of a site locally, DS will append the .dev.cc TLD which will only exist on your local computer.  DesktopServer modifies all instances of .dev.cc to the correct production domain when you push your site to live.  But, even if you don't use DS, you can use the .dev.cc domain.