# I can no longer access my local development (.dev) websites in Chrome - http is forced to https

Tags: google-chrome, local

Yesterday everything was working fine.
Had a Windows (10) update, restarted computer this morning and now my local dev sites no longer open in Chrome.

The sites still open in other browsers.

Chrome redirects test.dev to https://test.dev

Also tried http://test.dev, but that is also redirected.

The http version works fine in other browsers that don't force https.

What caused this and how do I fix it?
Please let me know if you need any extra information!

Comment: I've checked several other topics on this and it seems we are no longer "allowed" to use .dev as an extention and the only real solution is to use some other extention, like .test. Is this correct? I've tried removing localhost and my domains from chrome://net-internals/#hsts but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've switched all my local domains from .dev to .test
That solved my issue.

Apparently we're no longer "allowed" or supposed to use .dev extentions?
Not entirely sure how or why.

Don't really know how this happens after a Windows update. Didn't update Chrome as far as I know.

See also:
[How to stop Chrome from redirecting to HTTPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47735877/how-to-stop-chrome-from-redirecting-to-https?noredirect=1&lq=1)