# Chrome and Firefox cant connect to local server

Tags: apache, google-chrome, firefox, localhost, easyphp

I'm using Easyphp with MariaDB and for the last 4 months or so, everything has worked fine. Then i woke up yesterday and tried to get some work done and suddenly everything stopped working. However, I can access my local server through Microsoft Edge and firefox private browsing. chrome, chrome incognito, and normal firefox dont work though. I've reinstalled EasyPHP and chrome with no difference.

Here's an example of one of my hosts

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    DocumentRoot "C:/Projects/rbs/public"
    ServerName rbs.dev
    <Directory "C:/Projects/rbs/public">
        Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
        Deny from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Any help or suggestions on where to start with this would be really appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop Chrome from redirecting to HTTPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47735877/how-to-stop-chrome-from-redirecting-to-https)

Comment: Wow. That fixed it. I can't believe it was that simple. Thanks!