# Apache Dev Website Blocked by Chrome/Safari but not FireFox

Tags: apache, google-chrome, safari, macos-high-sierra

After upgrading my iMac to OSX High Sierra my dev website isn't accessible even after completely reconfiguring Apache and phpMyAdmin.

- localhost works (get default Apache index page showing "It works!")
- http://127.0.0.1/~Ross/wonderfest/web/index.php works in Chrome, Safari & FF
- wonderfest.dev does NOT work in Chrome or Safari, but DOES work in FF
- Error:

> This site can’t be reached wonderfest.dev refused to connect. Try:
>
> Checking the connection Checking the proxy and the firewall
>   ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

My /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf file contents:

```
<FilesMatch ".+\.html$">
 SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>

<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
 ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot "/Users/Ross/Sites/wonderfest"
 ServerName wonderfest.dev
 ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/wonderfest.dev-error_log"
 CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/wonderfest.dev.local-access_log" common

 <Directory "/Users/Ross/Sites/wonderfest">
   AllowOverride All
   Require all granted
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I guess my question boils down to: why does FF work in all cases, but not Safari & Chrome? I have mySQL up-and-running, and phpMyAdmin works fine, too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop Chrome from redirecting to HTTPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47735877/how-to-stop-chrome-from-redirecting-to-https)

Comment: Thank you! Changing my TLD to ".test" worked.