# Mac os High sierra vhost

Tags: apache, vhosts, macos-high-sierra

I've been working with apache vhost but after updating to mac os high sierra I have this issue and I made all the configuration:

If I enter this url, it works :

http://localhost/~macbook/planning/public/login

[image]

but if enter this one that I was using :

planning.dev

It becomes https://planning.dev and is not working

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are nothing to do with macOS High Sierra. This is known as a change for **.dev** domain on Chrome browser from version 63.

People was discussing about this from [How to stop Chrome from redirecting to HTTPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47735877/how-to-stop-chrome-from-redirecting-to-https)

Your `https://planning.dev` domain was forced under HTTPS connection automatically.

The temporary workaround is

- switch to another dev domain (`.test`, `.example`, `.invalid` or `.localhost`), you might also have to adapt them in your `/etc/hosts` file.
- using local IP (10.0.0.x, 192.168.x.x, ...)
- using loopback IP 127.0.0.1