# How can i open a react app in this url: js-api.local.dev?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I have been requested to do an app that communicates with another app, i am requested to open my app in the url: js-api.local.dev as this url is used for connecting my app with the other one, they communicate between each other , how can i make this possible?

Comment: What about chaning your `hosts` file to map `127.0.0.1` to `js-api.local.dev`?

Comment: I tried to do so but the app still opens in localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Chrome and Firefox force .dev domains to HTTPS via preloaded HSTS** and maybe other browsers do the same thing
 so you should use another tld sush as `.test` or `.localhsot` or you can try other solutions (e.g. https with self-signed certificates).

If you want to open your app with **js-api.local.test** for example:

- Add  `127.0.0.1     js-api.local.test` to your hosts file
- create a `.env` file in the root of your cra app and add: `HOST=js-api.local.test`

More info:
 [Chrome redirects .dev to https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47768289/chrome-redirects-dev-to-https)
[How to stop Chrome from redirecting to HTTPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47735877/how-to-stop-chrome-from-redirecting-to-https)
 [Chrome & Firefox now force .dev domains to HTTPS via preloaded HSTS](https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/)
 [Create React App - Advanced Configuration](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/advanced-configuration)