# Disable website redirection to HTTPS on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, http, redirect, https, hsts

I have a domain http://radiotn.com that is redirecting to HTTPS on chrome only.

I want to disable this redirection and run my website on HTTP because it contains external radio streamings that run on HTTP

The website doesn't redirect on Chrome private navigator nor in Firefox for example

I tried chrome on different devices and it always redirect to HTTPS.

In response headers there is "Non-Authoritative-Reason: HSTS"

I tried to remove it by following this thread but it didn't work: https://superuser.com/questions/565409/how-to-stop-an-automatic-redirect-from-http-to-https-in-chrome

I don't think that it's related to my chrome browser as I tried it on different devices and still get this redirection to HTTPS

I was using Cloudflare. I thought that it may related to cloudflare config.

So I changed my nameservers to redirecct directly to namecheap but this didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Questions about how to use web browsers are best asked at [su].

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Developers are much more likely than end users to need to be able to switch back and forth between http and https. I sure I'm not the only one who accidentally typed https://localhost/myserver and got horribly stuck because https does not exist for my local dev server.

Answer (score 9):

Type in: `chrome://net-internals/#hsts` in address bar of chrome.
At the bottom place the domain to delete from HSTS.

Comment: This solution does not work.

Answer (score 9):

Other answers didn't work for me. 
Eventually under: `Settings -> Privacy and Security -> Security` I found this toggle which I disabled:
[image]

Then all worked OK

Comment: This isn't working for me as of June 2023.

Comment: chrome://flags/#https-upgrades

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/565409/how-to-stop-an-automatic-redirect-from-http-to-https-in-chrome
you can find answer here

Answer (score 8):

Only solution that worked for me (trust me I tried it all)

Go to `chrome://settings/content/insecureContent` , add your website pattern under `Allowed to show insecure content`

Example:

`[*.]demo.com`

Note: the browser app Chrome on Android Smartphones/Tablet does not permit the changing of these settings, a workaround could be to install Kiwi browser app, it's like having Chrome desktop on your Android device. In Kiwi you can change these settings as explained in this answer.

Comment: it doesn't exist aymore

Comment: Which version of Chrome are you using? 
I use `119.0.6045.159` (should be the latest) and it exists there

Comment: I'm using Chrome 120.0.6099.210 on a Samsung Android Tablet

Comment: It works using Kiwi browser on Android, thanks

Comment: It works for Chrome 120.0.6099.234 as of Jan 25 2024. Thanks.

Comment: This solution does not work.

Comment: @Samira which version of chrome are you using? 
Works for `121.0.6167.184` as of Feb 21, 2024

Answer (score 3):

1. Click the lock in the browser address bar opposite the domain name
2. Select "Site Settings"
3. Click "Clear Data" against "cookies".
4. Then scroll down to "Insecure content" and click "Allow"