# How to disable http -> https in puppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer, chromium

says impossible: https://superuser.com/questions/1730252/how-to-ignore-hsts-on-chrome

how to manipulate `chrome://net-internals`? https://superuser.com/questions/565409/how-to-stop-an-automatic-redirect-from-http-to-https-in-chrome

this is unhelpful for my case: [How to disable Chrome HSTS permanently for a subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44650854/how-to-disable-chrome-hsts-permanently-for-a-subdomain)

using flags
[Disable website redirection to HTTPS on Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73875589/disable-website-redirection-to-https-on-chrome)

setting flags with switches

[Google Chrome - how can i programmatically enable chrome://flags some of the modules from disable mode to enabled mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17060363/google-chrome-how-can-i-programmatically-enable-chrome-flags-some-of-the-mod/17136627#17136627)

[Setting specific chrome flags in puppeteer (enable and disable)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50607866/setting-specific-chrome-flags-in-puppeteer-enable-and-disable)

switches missing `chrome://flags/#https-upgrades` - https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/chromium/+/trunk/chrome/common/chrome_switches.cc

Comment: Why do you want to do this (possible [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676))?

Comment: @ggorlen, there are proxies that cannot proxy https requests. I'd want to use http everywhere.

Comment: The question is still pretty unclear. I'd take a step back and write a clear explanation of what you're trying to accomplish in the post. This looks like a bunch of random links without context. What do each of the links mean?

Comment: @ggorlen, http -> https (means redirect). the links are saying hsts is responsible for that, so they are related. yet not understandable how disabling may be automated. there also one comment under an answer says https-upgrades flag is in charge of handling this behaviour

Comment: these are just materials I've looked into before posting question here. the answer stays "how to disable http -> https (auto redirect) in (chromium headless managed by) puppeteer"

Comment: there is +problem that https much harder to analyse (via packet capturing)

Comment: When I removed `args: ['--ignore-certificate-errors']` option from pupperteer.launch, browser doesn't redirect to https.